# If object value `num` is greater than `quota` in array, then add class to my element that has the same #id from my array objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a map in svg, each group with its #id represents a region:

```
<svg>
  <g id="CP1000"><path>...</path></g>
  <g id="CP1140"><path>...</path></g>
  <g id="CP1030"><path>...</path></g>
  ..
</svg>
```

I have a file with an array of objects with each region and its own data `name`, `quota` and `num`. Here's what my javascript file looks like:

```
var regions = [
  {id: 'CP1000', name: 'Bruxelles', quota: '20', num: '15'},
  {id: 'CP1140', name: 'Etterbeek', quota: '20', num: '12'},
  {id: 'CP1030', name: 'Schaerbeek', quota: '20', num: '21'},
  ...
];
```

What I need to do is to compare my `num` object value with `quota` within its unique `id` value. If `num` is greater than `quota`, then add a class `is-greater` to that `<g id="id">` element. For ex:

```
For id: 'CP1030', I need to compare if its `num` is greater than `quota`.
If it's true then add a class to my element <g id="CP1030">...</g>.
```

The script will look to find my item with id CP1030 in my page and I will have:

```
<svg>
  <g id="CP1000"><path>...</path></g>
  <g id="CP1140"><path>...</path></g>
  <g id="CP1030" class="is-greater"><path>...</path></g>
  ..
</svg>
```

That way I can fill this region id#CP1030 with specific background colour.
Any idea how to that in jQuery? Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery is primarily for amending the DOM and isn't really relevant to this problem. All you need is a `forEach()` loop over the objects in the array, something like this:

```js
var regions = [
  {id: 'CP1000', name: 'Bruxelles', quota: '20', num: '15'},
  {id: 'CP1140', name: 'Etterbeek', quota: '20', num: '12'},
  {id: 'CP1030', name: 'Schaerbeek', quota: '20', num: '21'},
];

regions.forEach(obj => {
  if (obj.num > obj.quota) 
    document.getElementById(obj.id).classList.add('is-greater');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <g id="CP1000"><path /></g>
  <g id="CP1140"><path /></g>
  <g id="CP1030"><path /></g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Hi again, sorry to bother you again I have another quick question. Why can we not do `document.getElementById(obj.id).addClass('is-greater');`? When I tried to do so I got `Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).addClass is not a function`

Just wondering why that's all

Comment: Becuase `getElementById()` returns an Element object, which doesn't have an `addClass()` method - that's part of jQuery. To fix this use eithe rnative methods only: `document.getElementById(obj.id).classList.add('is-greater')` or jQuery only: `$('#' + obj.id).addClass('is-greater')`

Comment: Hi Rory, I just tried the jQuery solution which didn't work to my #id. The first native solution indeed adds the class, not the Jquery one.

Comment: Have you included the jQuery library in the page? Try checking the console for errors

Comment: That's really odd. I can't replicate it: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/8btp3wdh/

Comment: Never mind, your example is working not in mine, don't worry thank you for your time.